# Weight and two way fixed effects in xtqreg

Tags: stata, quantile-regression

I am using `xtqreg` command in Stata to implement a quantile regression. I have two questions:

(1) How can I add weight for each observation in the regression? aweight does not work in `xtqreg`.

(2) How can I have two fixed effects? I want to have both year and id fixed effects.

Comment: Neither of these appears to be supported in this community-contributed command. You should ask on Statalist, where the second author is active;

Comment: Now cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1708943-weights-and-two-way-fixed-effects-in-xtqreg

Answer (score 1):

Try mmqreg (ssc install) which should allow for both